# Linq's static function 'Contain' is messing up with its content on a nested query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, t-sql

I'm trying to reduce the number of database queries and in doing so I'm attempting to retrieve a series of hierarchical entities (that were previously fetched recursively) in one go.

I've got a `Labels` property holding a set of strings:

```
public string[] Labels { get; set; } // new string[] {"{{a}}", "{{b}}", "{{c}}", "{{d}}", "{{e}}"};
```

that I'm using to construct a first query:

```
var IDeferredTopLabels= 
    db.labels
        .Where(l =>
            l.site_id == this.site_id &&
            this.Labels.Contains(l.name_for_code)
        )
    .Select(l => new LabelWithParentId { Label = l, ParentId = null });
```

The above, if inspected while debugging, would generate the following TSQL

```
SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[name_for_code], [t0].[site_id], [t0].[priority_level]
FROM [dbo].[labels] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[site_id] = 15) AND ([t0].[name_for_code] IN ('{{a}}', '{{b}}', '{{c}}', '{{d}}', '{{e}}'))
```

So far so good, following the `IDeferredToplabels` declaration I'm extending the first query with a `Union` specifying how child `Label` entities should be fetched:

```
var IDeferredWithChildLabels = IDeferredTopLabels
    .Union(
        db.label__labels
        .Where(ll => 
            db.labels
                .Where(l =>
                    l.site_id == this.site_id &&
                    this.Labels.Contains(l.name_for_code)
                )
            .Select(l => l.id)
            .Contains(ll.parent_label_id)
        )
    .Select(ll => new LabelWithParentId { Label = ll.label1, ParentId = ll.parent_label_id})
    );
```

Now if I inspect the TSQL generate is:

```
SELECT [t4].[id], [t4].[name_for_code], [t4].[site_id], [t4].[priority_level], [t4].[value] AS [ParentId]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[name_for_code], [t0].[site_id], [t0].[priority_level], NULL AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[labels] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[site_id] = 15) AND ([t0].[name_for_code] IN ('{{a}}', '{{b}}', '{{c}}', '{{d}}', '{{e}}'))
    UNION
    SELECT [t2].[id], [t2].[name_for_code], [t2].[site_id], [t2].[priority_level], [t1].[parent_label_id] AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[label__label] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[labels] AS [t2] ON [t2].[id] = [t1].[label_id]
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[labels] AS [t3]
        WHERE ([t3].[id] = [t1].[parent_label_id]) AND ([t3].[site_id] = 15) AND ([t3].[name_for_code] IN ('{{a}}', '{{b}}', '{{c}}', '{{a}}'0, '{{a}}'1))
        )
    ) AS [t4]
```

If you see at the end of this second TSQL Query, the part `IN ('{{a}}', '{{b}}', '{{c}}', '{{a}}'0, '{{a}}'1))`, the set of strings have some unespected 0 and 1 next to the second last and last element plus it is no longer the initial set of strings (ie '{{a}}', '{{b}}', '{{c}}', '{{d}}', '{{e}}') but instead `'{{a}}', '{{b}}', '{{c}}', '{{a}}', '{{a}}'`.

What I'm I doing wrong!?

I'm clueless, I appreciate your help, thank you.

EDIT:

I just tried to use an `int[]` and compare the `id` rather then the `name_for_code` and I'm still getting 1 and 0 appended to the last 2 elements of the array as well as the array elements are wrong:

```
SELECT [t4].[id], [t4].[name_for_code], [t4].[site_id], [t4].[priority_level], [t4].[value] AS [ParentId]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[name_for_code], [t0].[site_id], [t0].[priority_level], NULL AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[labels] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[site_id] = 15) AND ([t0].[id] IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
    UNION
    SELECT [t2].[id], [t2].[name_for_code], [t2].[site_id], [t2].[priority_level], [t1].[parent_label_id] AS [value]
    FROM [dbo].[label__label] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[labels] AS [t2] ON [t2].[id] = [t1].[label_id]
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[labels] AS [t3]
        WHERE ([t3].[id] = [t1].[parent_label_id]) AND ([t3].[site_id] = 15) AND ([t3].[id] IN (1, 2, 3, 10, 11))
        )
    ) AS [t4]
```

Comment: Do you still get this behaviour if the literal strings involved are `a b c d e` (ie without the `{{ }}`) ?

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this - why isn't your sql parameterized?  LinqToSql would generate parameterized queries.

Comment: @AakashM: I tried removing `{{ }}}` but I still get `IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'0, 'a'1))`

Comment: @David B: I do not understand it either, I'm using `Contains()` in the same project, several other places and it is always parameterized. I will try to make it an `int[]` and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the problem and actually it was not happening when running the code but only in debug mode and specifically it seems it is a bug in Scott Gu's [LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx)

That is why the TSQL that I was grabbing was not parameterized, @David B you made a very good point!

I will leave a comment on Scott Gu's page pointing to this question.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Try making a copy of `Labels` and using that in the second part of the query (the Union). EG:

```
string[] LabelsCopy = new string[5];
Labels.CopyTo(LabelsCopy, 0);
```

Then set a breakpoint after the query and inspect the contents of each array (or print out the contents of both arrays with `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',',Labels))`).

It's extremely unlikely that `.Contains()` is changing the contents of `Labels`, but if it is then you'll have proof.

Comment: I tried, it is not making any difference. However, if I inspect this.Labels or LabelsCopy, both have the correct values, before and after IDeferredWithChildLabels is defined.